# Show call stack in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, trace

To start with, I do not know if this is something trivial and common knowledge; I don't know, so am asking here.

I am running a 3rd party app and trying to nail down a problem for which I need to find out the call stack.

When I call a Bash script, it calls a number of other scripts and binaries, processing stuff and exits.

What I need is a way of finding out exactly which scripts and binaries it called. pstree shows a stack but only for a process that is currently executing.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80476/bash-accessing-function-call-stack-in-trap-function ?

Comment: Not quite. That shows how to display the stack in your own function.

Comment: I have a small hack which might help. https://gist.github.com/tripleee/0aea6984632c30956329

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the script with `bash -x`, which will produce output on standard error to show each command that is executed.

Comment: This only shows a trace for the current script, but scripts run as subprocesses will still run silently unless you separately hack them to also enable `set -x` one way or another.

Answer (score 15):

```
function stacktrace { 
   local i=1 line file func
   while read -r line func file < <(caller $i); do
      echo >&2 "[$i] $file:$line $func(): $(sed -n ${line}p $file)"
      ((i++))
   done
}
```

from https://gitlab.com/kyb/autorsync/-/blob/master/utils.bash#L84

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, this actually provides the stack trace that was requested in the question. bash -x has a lot of noise; this answer prints only what OP asked for.

Comment: I couldn't make this solution work. The modification of variables in the pipe triggers Shellcheck [SC2031](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2031).
I ended up using process substitution:
`while read line func file; do echo "[$i] $file:$line $func(): $(sed -n ${line}p $file)"; ((i++)); done < <(while caller $i; do ((i++)); done)`

Comment: It is strange.  I don't know if its a bash 2.x difference, but this definitely doesn't work in bash 4.x or 5.x.  I've edited the answer to reflect this.  If it looks strange, remember "caller" outputs nothing when it reaches the end.  When 'read' finds nothing to read, it sets a return code, so the while loop terminates as it should

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer oneliner traces (I find it convenient for logging), here is the example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trace() {
    local i pref="TRACE: "
    for (( i=${#FUNCNAME[@]}-1; i; i-- )); do
        echo -n "$pref${FUNCNAME[i]}[${BASH_LINENO[i-1]}]"
        pref=" -> "
    done
    echo ": $1"
}

# Test:

func_a() {
    count=-1
    (( count > 0 )) || trace "Unexpected count: $count"
}

func_b() {
    func_a
}

func_c() {
    func_b
}

func_c
```

The output is:

```
TRACE: main[27] -> func_c[24] -> func_b[20] -> func_a[16]: Unexpected count: -1
```